# place a minipage on the top of a page

Tags: positioning, minipage

I need to place a `minipage` on the **top** of a page. I use the `t` option, but seems not working.

```
\usepackage{abbrevs}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{times}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.8\textwidth}
      \begin{minipage}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
        \centering
        \adjustbox{width=0.7\textwidth} {
          \begin{tikzpicture}[text centered, nodes = {draw, minimum size = 22mm}]
            \matrix at (0, 0)
                    {
                      \node {$ 1 $}; & \node {$ 1 $}; \\
                      \node {$ *1 $}; & \node {$ *1 $}; \\
                    };
          \end{tikzpicture}
        }
        \captionof{figure}{fig 1.}
      \end{minipage}%
    \hfill
      \begin{minipage}[b]{0.46\textwidth}
        \centering
        \adjustbox{width=1.2\textwidth} {
          \begin{tikzpicture}[text centered, nodes = {draw, minimum size = 12mm}]
            \matrix at (0, 0)
                    {
                      \node {$ 2 $}; & \node {$ \forall $}; \\
                      \node {$ 2 $}; & \node {$ 2 $}; \\
                    };
          \end{tikzpicture}
        }
        \captionof{figure}{fig 2.}
      \end{minipage}
    \end{minipage}
```

Comment: Please add a complete minimal example illustrating the problem mentioned.

Comment: Perhaps you want to place the `minipage` above the text area?

Comment: To add to Gonzalo Medina's question, maybe he/she needs it as a watermark.

Comment: Hi all, thanks for replies. I wish the final effect seems like `\begin{figure}[t]`, not in the **top margin**. Because there are two figures in the minipage, I cannot use figure to wrap the minipage again.

Comment: @Kejia柯嘉: Please provide a minimal example.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `[t]` option does not represent where the `minipage` will be placed on the page, but actually represents the internal alignment of the material.

If you want the `minipage` to be put at the top of a page, you can put it into a floating environment- either a `figure` or `table` (or you could even create your own if you wanted to).

So, the following would get you closer to what you want

```
\begin{figure}[!t]
    \begin{minipage}{.3\textwidth}
    ...
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

Of course, now that your `minipage` is floating, it may not be in the order that you desire with respect to your other content. If you don't want it to float, then you might also look into `\clearpage` or `\newpage`