# two pieces of text in the left bottom corner and right bottom corner of the page

Tags: tables, positioning, minipage

I would like to have two short 3 lines text aligned to the bottom of the page and split to the extrems of the page. I was trying using minipage:

```
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
xxx
xxx
xxx
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
yyy
yyy
yyy
\end{minipage}
```

but I didn't know how to place it on the bottom of the page. I've found  [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47900/place-a-minipage-on-the-top-of-a-page), but when I've put this in figure environment, the two pieces of the text (x and y) appeard one behid the other and not next to each other.

I've tried this:

```
\begin{tabular*}{0.99\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill} } l r}
 xxx & yyy \\
 xxx & yyy \\
 xxx & yyy \\
\end{tabular*}
```

but the text in`tabular` is indented.

What is the simplest methode to achieve what I want?

Comment: Just a wild guess: `\noindent\begin{tabular*}{0.999\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}lr@{}}...\end{tabular}`?

Comment: To push the Gustavo's table to the bottom, put `\vspace*{\fill}` before it! (Note: You could use `\vfill` if something else was printed on that page, but `\vspace*{\fill}` will also work if there is no other text yet.)